# Effeciency : Imagemagick vs. Java awt Graphics

Tags: java, performance, graphics, imagemagick

If my primary requirements are related to cropping and merging of images, in terms of efficiency with respect to running time, which would be better of these two :
1. Java awt Graphics package using the getSubImage function and drawImage functions
2. Executing Imagemagick commands like crop etc from within a java program.

I wish to know which of the two will be faster and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Java BufferedImages are not fast, however you would need to do a lot of image processing for it to overcome the overhead of executing ImageMagick externally.

If you really need to do a lot of image processing then you might want to consider using OpenGL and having the graphics card do it.

But really, start doing things the simple way using BufferedImage and only worry about complicating that if it is too slow.

Comment: Thanks @Tim :) Yeah I'm using Bufferedimages but the image orocessing involved is minimal. I only need to crop an image and merge it with other images. Considering this, what you suggest in terms of speed